# Numerical error in implementation of iterative algorithm

Tags: computational-physics, iterative-method

I am trying to implement (in Python for now) low thrust orbit propagation for spacecraft using [universal variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_variable_formulation). For a given central body with the gravitational parameter $\mu$ and an orbit with the semi-major axis $a$ and the initial position $\vec{r}_0$ and velocity $\vec{v}_0$ at $t = t_0$ the position for a given time is given by:
$$
\vec{r} = \vec{r}_0 \ f(s) + \vec{v}_0 \ g(s)
$$
and the velocity by
$$
\vec{v} = \vec{r}_0\ \dot{f}(s) + \vec{v}_0\ \dot{g}(s)
$$

Where
$$
f(s) = 1-\left(\frac{\mu}{|\vec{r}_0|}\right) s^2 c_2(\alpha s^2) 
$$
$$
g(s) = t-t_0-\mu s^3c_3(\alpha s^2)
$$

With $\alpha=\frac{\mu}{a}$, $c_n$ the n-th Stumpff function and $s$ the solution of
$$
t-t_0=|\vec{r}_0| s \ c_1(\alpha s^2) + |\vec{r}_0| s^2 \ c_2(\alpha s^2) + \mu s^3 \ c_3(\alpha s^3)
$$

I am calculating $s$ by using Newton's Method and everything works fine for scenarios without thrust. The orbit is elliptical and closed, parabolic for higher initial velocities, if I choose a $\vec{r}_0$, $\vec{v}_0$ and $t_0$ and propagate $t$ forward.

For cases with thrust where I would change the velocity in every iteration

$$
\vec{v}_{k} = \vec{v}_{k-1} + \vec{a}_{k} \cdot \Delta t
$$

it is necessary to update $\vec{r}_0$ and $\vec{v}_0$ every time, propagate $\Delta t$ forward and repeat instead of choosing initial conditions and just propagating $t$ forward. In preparation for that I chose not to add any velocity so both approaches should yield the same results.

**Here is my Problem:**
Even after the first iteration the differences are large and the error increases fast

[[image: blue: fixed initial conditions, propagating <span class=]$t$; red: propagating initial conditions, fixed $\Delta t$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opE2X.png)

- blue: fixed initial conditions, propagating $t$
- red: propagating initial conditions, fixed $\Delta t$

I thought I could solve this by using a more advanced integration algorithm like Runge-Kutta and tried to calculate every iteration in as few steps as possible but I was not able to transform the equations so that I could use Runge-Kutta (since it is not an ODE) and reducing the steps did not help at all.

Can someone help to fix this or give any hints to why this error is so large?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import newton
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import cmath as mth
 
 
plt.close("all")
 
#defining some constants
gamma           = 4*np.pi**2*6.6108**3
 
#stumpff functions
f_c0            = lambda x: mth.cos(x)
f_c1            = lambda x: mth.sin(x)/x
f_c2            = lambda x: (1.-mth.cos(x))/(x*x)
f_c3            = lambda x: (x-mth.sin(x))/(x*x*x)
 
#f
f_uvf           = lambda mu,r0,s,a,sq:     1.-mu/r0*s**2*f_c2(sq)
#g
f_uvg           = lambda t,tau,mu,s,a,sq:  t-tau-mu*s**3*f_c3(sq)
#df/dt
f_uvdf          = lambda mu,r,r0,s,a,sq:   -(mu/(r*r0))*s*f_c1(sq)
#dg/dt
f_uvdg          = lambda mu,r,s,a,sq:      1.-mu/r*s**2*f_c2(sq)
    
 
def getPos(t,tau,r0,v0,mu,a):
    
    #absolute values of initial position and velocity
    r0a     = np.sqrt(r0[0]*r0[0]+r0[1]*r0[1])
    v0a     = np.sqrt(v0[0]*v0[0]+v0[1]*v0[1])
    
    #semi-major axis from gravitational paramteter and initial conditions
    a       = (2./r0a-v0a**2./mu)**-1.
    
    #defining function to numericly find s
    def f_root(s):
        sqrtx = mth.sqrt(mu/a*s**2)   
        return r0a*s*f_c1(sqrtx)+r0a*s**2*f_c2(sqrtx)+mu*s**3*f_c3(sqrtx)-(t-tau)
 
    #using newton algorithm to evaluate the function
    s       = newton(f_root,2,maxiter=100,tol=1e-10)
    
    sq = mth.sqrt(mu/a*s**2)
    
    #calculating the functions
    f       = f_uvf(mu,r0a,s,a,sq)
    g       = f_uvg(t,tau,mu,s,a,sq)
    
    #calculating new position
    rx          = r0[0]*f + v0[0]*g
    ry          = r0[1]*f + v0[1]*g
    
    #absolute value of new position
    ra          = np.sqrt(rx**2+ry**2)
    
    df          = f_uvdf(mu,ra,r0a,s,a,sq)
    dg          = f_uvdg(mu,ra,s,a,sq)
    
    #calculating new velocity
    vx          = r0[0]*df + v0[0]*dg
    vy          = r0[1]*df + v0[1]*dg
 
    
    return (rx,ry),(vx,vy)
    
 
#setting initial values
initial_r   = (0.,5.)
initial_v   = (30.,0.)
 
#setting simulation parameters
dt          = .001
frames      = 1000
 
#setting up plot
scale = 5.5
 
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal', autoscale_on=False,xlim=(-scale, scale), ylim=(-scale, scale))
ax.grid()
 
#creating list with points in time to propagate t
t   = np.linspace(0,frames*dt,frames+1)
 
#creating list for position and velocity for fixed initial conditions while propagating t (method 1)
data_r = [initial_r]
data_v = [initial_v]
 
#same for propagating initial conditions, fixed delta t (method 2)
data2_r = [initial_r]
data2_v = [initial_v]
 
for i in range(len(t)-1):
    #evaluating with method 1
    data = getPos(t[i],0,data_r[0],data_v[0],gamma,3.5)
    #evaluating with method 2
    data2= getPos(dt,0,data2_r[i],data2_v[i],gamma,3.5)
    
    #adding data to lists
    data_r.append(data[0])
    data_v.append(data[1])
    
    data2_r.append(data2[0])
    data2_v.append(data2[1])
 
#formatting data
data_r = list(zip(*data_r))
data_v = list(zip(*data_v))
data2_r = list(zip(*data2_r))
data2_v = list(zip(*data2_v))
 
#plot data
ax.plot(data_r[0],data_r[1],'b')
ax.plot(data2_r[0],data2_r[1],'r')
 
#creating line for animation
line, = ax.plot([0], [0], 'o-', lw=2)
 
#animation loop
def animate(i):
    
    #accelerate animation
    di = i*10
    
    #animating mehtod 1
    #line.set_data([0,data_r[0][di]],[0,data_r[1][di]])
    
    #animating mehtod 2
    line.set_data([0,data2_r[0][di]],[0,data2_r[1][di]])
 
    return line,
 
#creating animation
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=500, frames=frames, repeat=False)
 
plt.show()

RAW Paste Data
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import newton
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import cmath as mth


plt.close("all")

#defining some constants
gamma           = 4*np.pi**2*6.6108**3

#stumpff functions
f_c0            = lambda x: mth.cos(x)
f_c1            = lambda x: mth.sin(x)/x
f_c2            = lambda x: (1.-mth.cos(x))/(x*x)
f_c3            = lambda x: (x-mth.sin(x))/(x*x*x)

#f
f_uvf           = lambda mu,r0,s,a,sq:     1.-mu/r0*s**2*f_c2(sq)
#g
f_uvg           = lambda t,tau,mu,s,a,sq:  t-tau-mu*s**3*f_c3(sq)
#df/dt
f_uvdf          = lambda mu,r,r0,s,a,sq:   -(mu/(r*r0))*s*f_c1(sq)
#dg/dt
f_uvdg          = lambda mu,r,s,a,sq:      1.-mu/r*s**2*f_c2(sq)
    

def getPos(t,tau,r0,v0,mu,a):
    
    #absolute values of initial position and velocity
    r0a     = np.sqrt(r0[0]*r0[0]+r0[1]*r0[1])
    v0a     = np.sqrt(v0[0]*v0[0]+v0[1]*v0[1])
    
    #semi-major axis from gravitational paramteter and initial conditions
    a       = (2./r0a-v0a**2./mu)**-1.
    
    #defining function to numericly find s
    def f_root(s):
        sqrtx = mth.sqrt(mu/a*s**2)   
        return r0a*s*f_c1(sqrtx)+r0a*s**2*f_c2(sqrtx)+mu*s**3*f_c3(sqrtx)-(t-tau)

    #using newton algorithm to evaluate the function
    s       = newton(f_root,2,maxiter=100,tol=1e-10)
    
    sq = mth.sqrt(mu/a*s**2)
    
    #calculating the functions
    f       = f_uvf(mu,r0a,s,a,sq)
    g       = f_uvg(t,tau,mu,s,a,sq)
    
    #calculating new position
    rx          = r0[0]*f + v0[0]*g
    ry          = r0[1]*f + v0[1]*g
    
    #absolute value of new position
    ra          = np.sqrt(rx**2+ry**2)
    
    df          = f_uvdf(mu,ra,r0a,s,a,sq)
    dg          = f_uvdg(mu,ra,s,a,sq)
    
    #calculating new velocity
    vx          = r0[0]*df + v0[0]*dg
    vy          = r0[1]*df + v0[1]*dg

    
    return (rx,ry),(vx,vy)
    

#setting initial values
initial_r   = (0.,5.)
initial_v   = (30.,0.)

#setting simulation parameters
dt          = .001
frames      = 1000

#setting up plot
scale = 5.5

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal', autoscale_on=False,xlim=(-scale, scale), ylim=(-scale, scale))
ax.grid()

#creating list with points in time to propagate t
t   = np.linspace(0,frames*dt,frames+1)

#creating list for position and velocity for fixed initial conditions while propagating t (method 1)
data_r = [initial_r]
data_v = [initial_v]

#same for propagating initial conditions, fixed delta t (method 2)
data2_r = [initial_r]
data2_v = [initial_v]

for i in range(len(t)-1):
    #evaluating with method 1
    data = getPos(t[i],0,data_r[0],data_v[0],gamma,3.5)
    #evaluating with method 2
    data2= getPos(dt,0,data2_r[i],data2_v[i],gamma,3.5)
    
    #adding data to lists
    data_r.append(data[0])
    data_v.append(data[1])
    
    data2_r.append(data2[0])
    data2_v.append(data2[1])

#formatting data
data_r = list(zip(*data_r))
data_v = list(zip(*data_v))
data2_r = list(zip(*data2_r))
data2_v = list(zip(*data2_v))

#plot data
ax.plot(data_r[0],data_r[1],'b')
ax.plot(data2_r[0],data2_r[1],'r')

#creating line for animation
line, = ax.plot([0], [0], 'o-', lw=2)

#animation loop
def animate(i):
    
    #accelerate animation
    di = i*10
    
    #animating mehtod 1
    #line.set_data([0,data_r[0][di]],[0,data_r[1][di]])
    
    #animating mehtod 2
    line.set_data([0,data2_r[0][di]],[0,data2_r[1][di]])

    return line,

#creating animation
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=500, frames=frames, repeat=False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: If decreasing $\Delta t$ or increasing your precision for $s$ does not resolve the matter then it's presumably an implementation issue in which case you'll need to post your code for help.

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: And yes, of course decreasing $\Delta t$ helps but still energy is not conserved and the orbit changes overtime

Comment: While I can't spot the error with a cursory look at the code, it seems clear to me from your results that the error is with your evaluation of the new velocity...